# Java catch IOException

Tags: java, exception, ioexception

I think this is basic stuff but i'm not sure what to do. Why do I get `IOException never thrown in body of corresponding try statement`

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        File inputFile = null ;

        try
        {
            inputFile = new File("records.txt") ;   
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.print("file not found!") ;
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The File constructor in itself doesn't do very much.

It is not until you actually start doing actual operations that IOExceptions can be thrown.

Comment: Nice and simple answer +1. I might add that IOException is a checked exception. If the File constructor could throw it, it would not compile without the catch... if you remove the catch you see that it still compiles, hence IOException is not thrown there.

Answer (score 5):

It never throws an IOException. Creating a File object does not connect it to anything on the disk. That is, there is no IO.

If you try to read or write from a File object that does not have a corresponding file on the disk you'll get IOExceptions. Such as if you try to getCanonicalPath from a File that is not actually on the disk.

Answer (score 2):

Because you can instantiate File **object** with any string you want. You will get the exception later, when you try to read / write / open the actual file.

Answer (score 1):

[`File(String)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.lang.String%29) does not throw `IOException`, so you can't catch one at that time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check whether a file exists, do that with `file.exists()`. Apart from that:

- never swallow exceptions - always log the stacktrace or rethrow the exception (wrapping it in a runtime exception for example)
- don't rely on exception handling for the program flow - these should be exceptional cases.

Comment: There's a general principle in programming that goes something like this: "It's better to beg forgiveness than ask permission". That's because between you calling `file.exists` and you calling (say) `file.open`, the file may have been (say) deleted. If you instead assume the file will exist and try to open it, catching the exception otherwise, you don't get this issue.